# Firefox extension to find out which Javascript event is bound to an inspected element?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, dom-events

One can bind Javascript events to html elements without using inline declarations.

Is there a way when inspecting an html element to know which events are bound to the element?
I want to know about the events defined by the developer and not the internal ones that come with the browser.

So if I hover over an element and a menu shows up, I want to know which method caused it.

I have been trying Event Spy with the Code inspector but it logs too many of the internal ones, unless I am not using it right.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## [Visual event 2](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2)

[image: Visual event]
<sub>(source: [tinygrab.com](http://new.tinygrab.com/2c76fd8c3ea0ac6d22b28e3d46d6c480.png))</sub>

> Visual Event is an open source Javascript bookmarklet which provides debugging information about events that have been attached to DOM elements.

Comment: Cool. Keep in mind that it only recognizes event listeners added using on of supported libraries, not using the raw DOM API (addEventListener).

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to enumerate listeners added with addEventListener in Firefox core ([bug 448602](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=448602)).

There may be workarounds, but I'm not aware of any. See also [How to find event listeners on a DOM node when debugging or from the JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node)

[edit] Oh wait, determine "which events are bound"? Did you mean which events can fire on the node? If so, you should clarify your question.

Comment: I want to know the event handlers that were added in JQuery's Ready() function. Events like change, blur, click, etc..

Comment: If the events handlers are attached using jquery, then NV's answer is what you need.

Comment: The bug report you linked to has links at the bottom to documentation on how to get listeners. Looks like this solution is for privileged code though (Firefox addons).

Comment: @NoBugs: right, since I have posted my answer, a workaround internal was implemented for Firebug. As far as I know, there's still no web API for this, although I haven't been following the developments in this area closely lately.

Answer (score 0):

[From Firefox 33](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/33.0/releasenotes/) this feature (Display which elements have listeners attached) is added to inspector in [firefox-developer-tools](/questions/tagged/firefox-developer-tools). You can see `ev` or `event` icon next to elements which have event listeners. Clicking that displays a listing of all the event listeners bound to the element.

[image]

[MDN - Examine Event Listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_event_listeners)